# some HTML pictures are not loading on certain devices

Tags: html, image

I am writing a website in html and css for school and on the school computers the pictures aren't loading correctly.

At home I have an Apple Mac and the pictures are loading fine there. I used a spare windows computer lying around in my house and the pictures were loading fine there as well. when I got to school and used one of their windows computers though the pictures were not loading, the alternate text under the alt attribute was loading. Could this be as simple as the school computers are too 'slow' to run these pictures?

I know this may be a hard question to answer but any ideas even if they don't work will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The school computers might be blocking the images' sources. Check with an administrator and ask for an unblocked database.

Comment: some images are loading though and some are not

Comment: Are they all coming from the same source/database?

Comment: It might help if you share a bit of code

Comment: all pictures are in the same folder together

Comment: what code do you mean? I don't think its the codes problem as well, as I stated before it is loading on some devices and not others

Comment: I don't think the code is the actual problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230277/discussion-between-rojo-and-n-g).